# pdoPage не выводит пагинацию

Tags: modx

Почему не выводит пагинацию:

```
[[*pagetitle:is=`Новости`:then=`
            <div class="news__content">
                <div class="news__items">
                    [[!pdoPage?
                      &element=`getImageList`
                      &limit=`9`
                      &tvname=`news_cards`
                      &tpl=`news_cardTpl`
                      &docid=`[[*id]]`
                    ]]
                </div>
                [[!+page.nav]]
            </div>
        `
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

news_cards Tv:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
news_cardTpl:

```
<div class="news__item">
    <!-- <a href="#"> -->
        <div class="news-item__wrapper">
            <a href="#">
                [[getImageList?
                    &value=`[[+images]]`
                    &limit=`1`
                    &tpl=`news_imgTpl`
                ]]
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <h3 class="news-item__title">[[+title]]</h3>
            </a>
            <p class="news-item__text">[[+text]]</p>
            <div class="news-item__bottom">
                <span class="news-item__date">[[+date]]</span>
                <a href="#" class="news-item__link">Подробнее</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- </a> -->
</div>
```

news_imgTpl:

```
<img src="[[+image:pthumb=`wp=506&hp=380&zc=1`]]" alt="" class="news-item__img">
```

Comment: Что у вас внутри `news_cards` TV? как выглядит чанк `news_cardTpl` ?

Comment: Anton Tarasov, я прикрепил к вопросу

Comment: @Anton Tarasov, ещё не подскажите, как мне на главной отрисовать новости, которые только в шаблоне "news", пробовал через pdoField, но не получается.
https://pastenow.ru/c77fadf697f26f5dd33bce9833443313

Comment: У вас стоит ограничение количества выводимых элементов 9 (`&limit=9`) и на скриншоте 9 элементов в `news_cards Tv` т.е. все элементы на одной странице вмещаются, других страниц нет и пагинации нет, может в этом дело? Сам элемент пагинации добавляется только он пустой

Comment: Для фильтрации по шаблону есть параметр `&templates` - Список шаблонов, через запятую, для фильтрации результатов. Если id шаблона начинается с дефиса, ресурсы с ним исключается из выборки. По умолчанию `pdoPage` принимает все параметры `pdoTools` и кроме того, некоторые свои

Comment: Спасибо, насчёт пагинации вы правы, упустил момент

Comment: Не подскажите как отдельно ещё новость отрисовывать

Comment: @Vadim вам для новостей(как пытаетесь выводить, покажите) на главной тоже пагинация нужна(и сколько новостей? используйте &limit)? если нет попробуйте pdoResources. выше коллега верно уточнил про наследование параметров в пакете pdoTools. Да и &templates поможет.

Comment: @Anton Tarasov, спасибо и вам, я через вложенные ресурсы наверное сделаю новости